# Hiding NSPanel through a timer in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I am new to Cocoa and would like to know how to hide an NSPanel when a timer tick, I have tried to call
[myNSPanel orderout:self], the code runs but the panel is still there. Do I need to do something different? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the selector is `orderOut:`, and selectors are case-sensitive, so if your code actually says `orderout:`, then you're getting a does-not-respond-to-selector exception (which you can see in the Debugger Console) and that's why your code isn't working.

If it still doesn't work after you fix that, make sure `myNSPanel` (which I assume is an outlet) is actually hooked up to the panel in question. A very common mistake is to forget to connect the outlet; when you do this, the pointer in the outlet variable is `nil`, and a message to `nil` simply does nothing.

You can check this by logging the pointer: `NSLog(@"%p", myNSPanel);`. After that statement runs, the Debugger Console will contain a line telling you what pointer was in the `myNSPanel` variable. If it's `0x0`, that's `nil`.